# SQL Filtering Help: What does col_name+1 and col_name-1 do?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I'm given this problem:
*Which country has a population that is more than Canada but less than Poland? Show the name and the population.*

The query I wrote works fine:

```
SELECT name, population FROM world
WHERE population > 
(SELECT population FROM world
WHERE name = 'Canada')
AND
population < 
(SELECT population FROM world
WHERE name = 'Poland')
```

However, the answer key shows something significantly more elegant:

```
SELECT name,population FROM world
WHERE population BETWEEN
(SELECT population+1 FROM world WHERE name='Canada')
AND
(SELECT population-1 FROM world WHERE name='Poland')
```

Question: what does the *population+1* and *population-1* actually do? I retrieved population, population+1, and population-1, and all they seem to do is add one and subtract one from the resulting column values. Why is this necessary for the problem I'm trying to solve? Why I can't I just do:

```
SELECT name,population FROM world
WHERE population BETWEEN
(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name='Canada')
AND
(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name='Poland')
```

Running the above query returns an incorrect result, despite it (in my mind) being equivalent to there my original query, which returned the correct results!

Any help wrapping my head around this is much appreciated!

*Note: using sqlzoo.net platform to run my queries.*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version is better.  The alternative version is just adding 1 or subtracting 1 from the population.  Why?  Because `between` includes the end points and the question apparently does not want the end points.

Hence, `>` and `<` is a much better option than trying to cajole `between` to do something it is not supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thank you for both the logical answer and the style recommendation :)